# Windows 7 - Can't get virtualbox ubuntu to connect to the internet

Tags: windows-7, networking, ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm connected to my work's wireless network, and from there I am connected to a VPN (of my company's main campus). I am trying to set up VirtualBox to allow Ubuntu 14.04 to connect to the internet, but everything I have tried has failed.

Currently I have the following settings in "Network".

Checked Enable Network Adapter

Attached To: NAT

Adapter Type: PCnet-FAST III

Checked Cable Connected

Every place I've read online says this should work - I don't need to do any fancy servers or anything on the VM, I just want it to have internet access. I turned off my firewall while changing this settings, so I know that's not the problem.

Comment: putting aside virtualbox. What happens if you disconnect from the VPN can you then no longer access the internet? the web?

Comment: I can still access the internet without the VPN. The VPN is solely for connecting to an intranet on the main campus, I believe. Network and Sharing Center says that both provide "Internet", but since I can't connect to the VPN without internet, I can't really test it the other way.

Comment: So how is the VPN relevant?  And have you tried other OSs in virtualbox - can they access the Internet?

Comment: I don't know if it is relevant - I'm not very good at networking, so I figured someone else might know. I haven't tried other OSs in virtualbox primarily because of space limitations on my computer.

Comment: the VPN isn't relevant and thus from a troubleshooting perspective, you're making your problem sound harder than it is, and it'd simplify it if you didn't even mention the VPN.  I have an OS of about 200MB.. Win 7 PE I made https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E0eslpRmznE

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a HTTP proxy to connect to the Internet from your desktop PC, you may need to setup VirtualBox's settings to use the same proxy settings.

On OSX, this is done from the Virtual Box Menu > Preferences Menu > Proxy tab.